# Difference between rows in sql based on rows number (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-number

I have a problem. I have table with following columns and sample data:

```
RN   Date       Time     
---------------------
1  2015-02-02    12
2  2015-02-02    25
3  2015-02-02    27
1  2015-02-08    42
2  2015-02-08    45
1  2015-03-01    60
2  2015-03-01    62
3  2015-03-01    63
4  2015-03-01    63
```

I need get a difference between time start and time end of every day.

For example:

```
27-12
45-42
63-60
```

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  Date, max(Time) as mx, min(Time) as mn, max(Time) - min(Time) as diff 
from table_name 
group by Date
```